# Cloning Standard:S0 database to a Basic edition (test developmen)

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

really simple doubt, guess it is a bug, or something I got wrong

I have a databse in Azure, as Standard:S0 Tier, now 178 mb, and I want to make a copy (in a master's procedure) but with result database in BASIC pricing tier

Tought as:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDB_2 AS COPY OF MyDB ( EDITION = 'Basic')
```

With unhappier result :

> Database is created as pricing tier  Standard:S0

Then tried:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDB_2 AS COPY OF MyDB ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE =  'Basic' ) 

or

CREATE DATABASE MyDB_2 AS COPY OF MyDB ( EDITION = 'Basic', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE =  'Basic' )
```

With even unhappy result :

> ERROR:: Msg 40808, Level 16, State 1, The edition 'Standard' does not support the service objective 'Basic'.

tried also:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDB_2 AS COPY OF MyDB ( MAXSIZE = 500 MB, EDITION = 'Basic', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE =  'Basic' )
```

with unhappier result :

> ERROR:: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Incorrect syntax near 'MAXSIZE'.

.

**May I be doing something not allowed ?**

Comment: Following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn268335.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: strange,i was not able to repro the issue.I have S0 DB and just created a copy using following command  `CREATE DATABASE MyDB_2 AS COPY OF PerformanceV3 ( EDITION = 'basic') 
`

Comment: further your syntax error is due to as copy of use like below `CREATE DATABASE hito   
 ( MAXSIZE = 500 MB, EDITION = 'standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S1' ) ; `

Comment: Seriously, not kidding ::  https://ibb.co/crNAT5

Answer (score 0):

But if you copy your database via portal, you'd notice that basic tier is not available with message'**A database can only be copied within the same tier as the original database.**'. The behavior is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy):'*You can select the same server or a different server, its service tier and performance level, a different performance level **within the same service tier (edition)**. After the copy is complete, the copy becomes a fully functional, independent database. **At this point, you can upgrade or downgrade it to any edition**. The logins, users, and permissions can be managed independently.*'